# Specific group by latest date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a SQL query on the following set of data

```
date       creation_date    value
------------------------------------
2018-01-01 2017-05-05       1
2018-01-02 2017-05-05       0
2018-01-03 2017-05-05       1
2018-01-04 2017-05-05       0
2018-01-05 2017-05-05       1
2018-01-06 2017-05-05       1
2018-01-02 2017-05-11       5
```

I want to get the following results

```
2018-01-01 2017-05-05       1
2018-01-02 2017-05-11       5
2018-01-03 2017-05-05       1
2018-01-04 2017-05-05       0
2018-01-05 2017-05-05       1
2018-01-06 2017-05-05       1
```

Basically I want to get all the dates, group it by dates and get the latest creation date and get the value for that creation date.

I tried

```
select date, max(Creation_date), value 
from datasource
group by date, blocked
```

but that doesn't do it.

Comment: what if there are many rows containing the latest `Creation_Date`?

Comment: @Hadi Many rows contaning the latest Creation_Date? Please explain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use query like this:

```
select *
from (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by date, blocked order by creation_date desc) seq
     from datasource) t
where t.seq = 1;
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8642b/4)

Comment: if there are many rows containing the latest `Creation_Date`, this will choose one row randomly. But according to the OP informations provided, this solves the issue

Comment: @Hadi if you want all of them you can use `rank()` function instead ;).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use subquery and join with it

```
SELECT d.*
FROM datasource d
JOIN
  (
    SELECT [date],MAX(Creation_date) LastCreationDate
    FROM datasource
    GROUP BY [date]
  ) l
ON d.[date]=l.[date] AND d.Creation_date=l.LastCreationDate
```

Or the second variant if `Creation_date` is common for all the `[date]`

```
SELECT *
FROM datasource
WHERE Creation_date=(SELECT MAX(Creation_date) FROM datasource)
```

Comment: the second query will throw an exception if the are many dates = Max(Creation_Date)

Comment: @Hadi - It isn't possible. I use aggregate function MAX without GROUP BY - the subquery returns only one row.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM datasource WHERE Creation_date = ....` if there are Many rows that contains the latest creation date, this will not return one row for each date, which is required by the OP

Comment: @mko - What about the first query? I wrote "Or the second variant if Creation_date is common for all the [date]".

Comment: @Leran2002 first query is fine